# Enable CORS for any port on localhost as well as for the list of specific domains

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

In ASP.Net core 6.0, I want to enable CORS for localhost as well as for the list of specific domains

I have implemented something like this

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly string nondevCORSPolicyName = "NonDevCorsPolicy";
    private readonly string devCORSPolicyName = "DevCorsPolicy";

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {       
        ....
        services.AddCors(opt =>
        {
            opt.AddPolicy(name: this.nondevCORSPolicyName, builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("https://*.companydomain.com")
                    .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
            });
        });

        services.AddCors(opt =>
        {
            opt.AddPolicy(name: this.devCORSPolicyName, builder =>
            {
                builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost");
            });
        });
        ....
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors();
        .....
    }
}
```

Does it work?

Comment: did you tried running to see if it works or not before posting the question?

Comment: If you are using the Asp.Net Core 6.0 then the project will not have Startup.cs file. I would suggest you refer to [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0). It may help you get the code examples and detailed information about the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this as highlighted below

```
// CORS Policies
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost" || new Uri(origin).Host == "myweb.local");
    });
});


// Enable Cors
app.UseCors();
```